# get full path name using list comprehension in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

can I do something like this(actually the it doesn't work)

```
flist = [dirpath + f for f for fnames for dirpath, dirnames, fnames in os.walk('/home/user')]
```

thanks!

Comment: Double list comprehensions are hard to read and understand. Use for loops instead and your problems will go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fnames` doesn't exist yet. Swap the loops.

```
flist = [dirpath + f for dirpath, dirnames, fnames in os.walk('/home/user') for f in fnames]
```

Comment: +1: I *always* get multiple `for`s in a list comprehension the wrong way around. And now I avoid them entirely.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Avoiding them entirely is definitely the correct solution here.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd write it as a generator:

```
def filetree(top):
    for dirpath, dirnames, fnames in os.walk(top):
        for fname in fnames:
            yield os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
```

Then you can either use it in a loop:

```
for name in filetree('/home/user'):
    do_something_with(name)
```

or slurp it into a list:

```
flist = list(filetree('/home/user'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
flist = [os.path.join(pdir,f) for pdir, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/user') for f in files]
```

([`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) should be used instead of string concatenation to handle OS-specific separators and idiosyncrasies)

However, as several have already pointed out, multi-level list comprehension is not very readable and easy to get wrong.

Assuming you really do want to have the results in a list:

```
flist = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    flist.extend(os.path.join(root, f) for f in files)
    # to support python <2.4, use flist.extend([...])
```

If you're simply using `flist` as an intermediate storage to iterate through, you might be better off using a generator as shown in [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278369/get-full-path-name-using-list-comprehension-in-python/6280470#6280470).

Answer (score 0):

Using map:

```
map(lambda data: map(lambda file: data[0] + '\\' + file, data[2]), os.walk('/home/user'))
```

OR:

```
map(lambda data: map(lambda file: os.path.join(data[0], file), data[2]), os.walk('/home/user'))
```

Comment: `data[0] + '\\' + file` instead of `os.path.join` is a quite bad idea.

Comment: Sure, you right it was just an idea how to use map here, and string appending could be easily replaced with os.path.join.

Answer (score 0):

```
path = '/home/user/'   # keep trailing '/'
flist = [path+name for name in os.listdir(path)]
```